# Exported Data Frame in R with Write.csv has higher number of rows

Tags: r

I have a data frame which has 4970575 obs. of 13 variables
However, when I am exporting this
by using

```
write.csv(df, file='D:/xxx/yyy/test.csv', row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE, na="0")
```

it is creating a csv file which has more than 10 million rows?

Why on exporting is my R creating a much bigger data frame in csv which doesnt even exist?

Comment: What is `class(df)`? You are sure it's a data frame?  It's very hard to tell what the problem is without a reproducible example.

Comment: Could you show us a single row from your data frame, assuming that would fit in a reasonable amount of space?  This sounds like you wrote with the wrong separator and it resulted in new rows being created in the output file.

Comment: > class(df)
[1] "data.frame"
> sapply(df, typeof)
        origin  HC     group_name    position    device_type length_of_stay             ei            imp            clk           conv           cost  booking_value 
   "character"    "character"    "character"      "integer"      "integer"      "integer"      "integer"      "integer"      "integer"      "integer"       "double"       "double"

Comment: Yes it is a data frame. could be that my libraries are corrupt

Comment: You said it had **13** variables in the question but in the comment i could see only **12** variables. May be there is something wrong with your input file.